# Display objects related to requested object and children in Materialized Path trees

Tags: django, django-treebeard

## categories/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node


class Category(MP_Node):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    node_order_by = ['title']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Category: {}'.format(self.title)
```

## categories/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from .models import Category


class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'categories/category_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["products_in_category"] = self.object.products.filter(active=True)
        return context
```

## category_detail.html

```
.....
{% for p in products_in_category %}
       
        <h2><a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></h2>

.....
```

The code above works well to display products that belong to a specific category but I would also be able to display the products that belong to its descendants.

Example:

```
shoes

├── sneakers
│   ├── laced sneakers
│   └── non-laced sneakers
```

If I'm on the category page for sneakers I would want to be able to see products related to both Laced Sneakers and Non-laced Sneakers.

My thought was that the get_context_data could look something like this

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["products_in_category"] = self.object.get_descendants().products.filter(active=True)
    return context
```

But unfortunately, that did not work out.

I was thinking about using ListView instead but the category page will have a description describing the category and for that reason, I figure DetailView would be a better choice.

What do you guys think is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

try check this link, you can custom your template
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup